# Azure - Unable to remove Log Analytics and solution

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I’m trying to delete a log analytics and a solution but I’m unable to do it using the portal because of errors. Already made sure that nothing is referencing the log analytics (exception is the solution).

Tried to do it using azure powershell but I’m getting some error and I don’t know what else I can do… We don't have a support plan where we can ask for technical help...

Sample of powershell script i tried:

```
Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/bb7a9927-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/uwe-azukw-rg-test-infrastructure/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/uwe-azuks-law-test-logAnalytics" -Force
Remove-AzureRmResource : Conflict : The workspace cannot be deleted because it's used by the following solution resources: /subscriptions/bb7a9927-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/uwe-azukw-rg-test-infrastructure/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/uwe-azuks-law-test-logAnalytics/views/LogicAppsManagement(uwe-azuks-law-test-logAnalytics)
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/bb7a9927-703e-4045 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Conflict,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.RemoveAzureResourceCmdlet
```

Anyone has any idea how can I delete this view? If I try I get the error below but not sure how can I change the values

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/bb7a9927-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/uwe-azukw-rg-test-infrastructure/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/uwe-azuks-law-test-logAnalytics/views/LogicAppsManagement(uwe-azuks-law-test-logAnalytics)" -Force
Remove-AzureRmResource : NoRegisteredProviderFound : No registered resource provider found for location 'uksouth' and API version '2015-01-01' for type 'workspaces'. The supported api-versions are 
'2015-03-20, 2015-11-01-preview, 2017-01-01-preview, 2017-03-03-preview, 2017-03-15-preview, 2017-04-26-preview'. The supported locations are 'eastus, westeurope, southeastasia, australiasoutheast, 
westcentralus, japaneast, uksouth, centralindia, canadacentral, westus2, australiacentral, australiaeast, francecentral, koreacentral, northeurope, centralus, eastasia, eastus2, southcentralus, 
northcentralus, westus'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/bb7a9927-XXXX-XXXX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoRegisteredProviderFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.RemoveAzureResourceCmdlet
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a workspace I would suggest you to go with the cmdlet [Remove-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/Remove-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace?view=azps-2.0.0) / [Remove-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.operationalinsights/remove-azurermoperationalinsightsworkspace?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

To resolve 'NoRegisteredProviderFound' error, you may have to register the provider using cmdlet [Register-AzResourceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/register-azresourceprovider?view=azps-2.0.0) / [Register-AzureRmResourceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/register-azurermresourceprovider?view=azurermps-6.13.0) . For more details, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-register-provider-errors#solution-1---powershell) tutorial.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!